# Throwing conversion error while pass the value directly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This code throws an error when pass the value directly, but it doesn't show any error if pass the value by using parameter.

--It throws an Error

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ID INT=1234
SET @sql = N'select 
                [count]
            FROM dbo.Table_1 AS t
            JOIN dbo.table_2 AS t2 ON t.store_number = t2.store_number
            AND  t2.[year] = 17
            AND  t2.week_of_year = 6
            AND  t2.day_of_week = 2
            WHERE t.RC_ID = @ID'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

-- It throws an error

```
select 
    [count]
FROM dbo.Table_1 AS t
JOIN dbo.table_2 AS t2 ON t.store_number = t2.store_number
AND  t2.[year] = 17
AND  t2.week_of_year = 6
AND  t2.day_of_week = 2
WHERE t.ID = 1234

-- IT WORKS

DECLARE @sql
DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID = 1234

select 
    [count]
FROM dbo.Table_1 AS t
JOIN dbo.table_2 AS t2 ON t.store_number = t2.store_number
AND  t2.[year] = 17
AND  t2.week_of_year = 6
AND  t2.day_of_week = 2
WHERE t.ID = @ID
```

The Error is :

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'TEST' to data type int.

But there is No data like 'Test' in the table.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't tend to just make data up. If it's telling you it's having problems converting the value `TEST` to an integer, that data *will* be in there somewhere. Don't assume that any filters, etc, are performed in any particular order. You'll find the data in the table somewhere.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're correct we found that data .... from the view table, then table_1 is view table and that contains the value 'Test' , thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

One of your values that you are comparing as integers contains a bad value:

```
select t2.*
from table_2 t2
where try_convert(int, year) is null or try_convert(int, week_of_year) is null or
      try_convert(int, day_of_week) or try_convert(int, id) is null;
```

Whether the error occurs depends on the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

One of your table columns that you are filtering is not a numeric data type. When you do

```
WHERE VarcharColumn = 1
```

The SQL Server engine will always try to convert the most complex type to the simplest one, in this case "1" is a integer and VarcharColumn is `VARCHAR`, so the engine will try to convert all the values stored in VarcharColumn to integer before filtering by value 1. Since at least one value stored there is not an integer ("TEST") then the conversion fails and that message pops up.

You have 2 solutions:

- Validate and fix all your values in those columns so they are actually numbers and alter the data type to the corresponding one.
- Compare against the same type. `WHERE Column = '1'`

Of course always try to keep your data types in check.

Also in your dynamicSQL query, the declaration of the `@ID` must be inside your script (it's also missing an initial value).

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @sql = N'
    DECLARE @ID INT = 1

    select 
        [count]
    FROM dbo.Table_1 AS t
    JOIN dbo.table_2 AS t2 ON t.store_number = t2.store_number
    AND  t2.[year] = 17
    AND  t2.week_of_year = 6
    AND  t2.day_of_week = 2
    WHERE t.RC_ID = @ID'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

The reason for the error poping up 'sometimes' is because the different forms of your statement are making the execution plan do things in different order. If it tries to convert the varchar value to int first, it will fail. If it tries to convert the int value to varchar (for example) then it won't fail.

To find the problem, try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.Table_1 AS T
WHERE
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), T.store_number) = 'Test' OR
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), T.ID) = 'Test'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.table_2 AS T
WHERE
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), T.store_number) = 'Test' OR
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), T.[year]) = 'Test' OR
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), T.week_of_year) = 'Test' OR
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), T.day_of_week) = 'Test'
```

Comment: Hai @Ezequiel , thanks for your answer, if you read my question twice you'll get some more clarification about that, because when i pass the value as a parameter it doesn't show any kind of error, why ?

Comment: @ParvathiRajan the reason is because of different execution plans. It might seem like the same to us developers but the engine might work or access the data in a different way when a value is hardcoded than when it is passed by parameter. This is what i tried to explain with the paragraph of "The reason..."

Answer (score 0):

from what i see you are trying to use a parameter(@id) into the sp_executeSQL without never passing it. A quick fix would be to do something like that

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ID INT = 10
SET @sql = N'select 
            [count]
        FROM dbo.Table_1 AS t
        JOIN dbo.table_2 AS t2 ON t.store_number = t2.store_number
        AND  t2.[year] = 17
        AND  t2.week_of_year = 6
        AND  t2.day_of_week = 2
        WHERE t.RC_ID = ' + cast(@ID as nvarchar(20))
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, that was my mistake but It shows the same error.